# Use OmniAuth-identity just like another provider in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

In a Ruby on Rails application, I implemented as authentication OmniAuth with multiple providers(facebook and twitter for now), and I followed the steps from this  github page: [Managing Multiple Providers](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/managing-multiple-providers). Everything worked fine, I have a `User` class, in which a user is able to have many `Identity` objects.

Now I want to add a login with username and password, using [OmniAuth Identity](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-identity). My plan is to use the same `Identity` table, making this gem to store the `password_digest` field into the existing `oauth_token`, username into `uid` and use 'omniauth' as `provider`.

I am having difficulties in implementing this, trying to use the same model both for the externals auth(like facebook) and for this user/password, and I am wondering:

- Is this a recommended way to do this?
- Am I reinventing the wheel and such thing already exists?
- Should I use a new Model just for this type of login(OmniAuth Identity)?

At the moment, I have different problems, such as not being able to tell the Identity gem that provider should have only one value, or my SessionsController doesn't work now good when I register for the first time.